# AVPlayer currently playing item details and volume control in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, volume, avplayer, currentitem

I have tried AVPlayer for playing online http streamed music file, it works fine.

What is the way to get the current playing audio track name,artist etc?
Is there any way to adjust the volume of AVPlayer while playing music (using `UISlider`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the volume by:

```
player.volume = slider.value;
```

Comment: @Tim Cooper this can only done in AVAudioPlayer, am using AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;

//Display the artist, album, and song name for the now-playing media item.
//These are all UILabels.
self.songLabel.text   = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
self.artistLabel.text = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
self.albumLabel.text  = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
```

Comment: I think you can use this just for downloaded audios, not for streaming.

Comment: @KhalidUsman No its not downloaded audios. these are sync from itunes audio details.

Comment: @RKK property "nowPlayingItem" not found on object of type 'AVPlayer'

Comment: @RKK but i am using AVPlayer for online streaming music,,